# Apply bullets to the events from fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I am using jquery's '[fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)' plugin so as to show the events from a month.

I want to apply bullets to the event. I googled but I could not find anything about it whereas I know that we can apply css class. Is there some way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:list-item` if you want it to be displayed with bullets.

```
span{
display: list-item;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a class like this:

```
.yourcls .fc-event-title:before {
    content: "\025cf\00020"; /* U+25Cf=&bullet; */
}
```